# How to add a comment to a docx in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, docx

I didn't find a way to add a comment to an existing word document (docx) with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). I found nothing in the [JavaDoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) of POI, too. I'm glad for any help or hints.

**Edit:** I found the [XWPFCommentsDecorator](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFCommentsDecorator.html) class. However, I'm still struggling.

Comment: Maybe the docx4j equivalent gives you a some hints:  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/CommentsSample.java